# MongoDB modifiedCount doesn't equal matchedCount

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing a simple updateMany in MongoDB.  I'm using Studio3T.  Here is my query:

`db.getCollection("FineMapping").updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "algorith": "method" } } )`

This is a simple renaming of an attribute over all documents in the collection.  The response in Studio3T is:

```
{ 
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "matchedCount" : 7176215.0, 
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}
```

So all documents matched, but none are actually modified.  Why aren't the documents actually being modified?

Comment: Mongo is case sensitive. Check the field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is none of them have a field named `algorith`.

See the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/index.html#behavior

Comment: That would be why.  Sigh.  Sometimes I'm a muppet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IntelliShell, you can also right-click to bulk-edit multiple or all documents: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-documents-beginners-guide/#update-multiple-documents-e-g-matching-the-query-criteria-all-documents